# Error Installing Package: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: python-3.x, pip, package, pypi

I have Python 3.9.12 on my Windows computer and am trying to install a package with the following command `pip3 install [package]` to which I get the following:

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement [package] (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for [package]

I satisfy all the requirements for the package, I have pip-23.2.1. I've seen other users with the same issues but the solutions did not resolve my particular issue.

Thanks for all your help.

I made sure that I satisfied all the requirements for the package with the following command `pip3 install -r  [path]`.

I've also made sure my pip was up to date.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.